# Prolog, how to read value pro function for use in other function

Tags: function, prolog

I have this function:

```
func1(X).
```

After execution func1(a) return value X = n.
This is a second function:

```
other_func(z).
```

After execution other_func(z), it returns `true` or `false`.

And I need to use value from func1(a) to get a return value in the other function.

Example:

```
final_func(X) :- func1(X) = R , other_func(R).
```

but always returns false.

Comment: *After execution `func1(a)` return value `X = n`*. That's actually not possible. Prolog doesn't have functions that return values. It has predicates that succeed or fail. So when you say `func1(a)` returns `X = n` that doesn't make sense. Maybe you mean `func1(X)` succeeds with `X = n`? It's unclear.  Also note that lower case terms with no arguments represent *atoms* (they're constant), whereas variables must start with a capital letter or underscore.

Comment: The line `func1(X) = R` in your code doesn't do what you think. `func1(X)` as I mentioned doesn't return a value. `func1(X) = R` in Prolog attempts to unify the terms `func1(X)` and `R` through some instantiation of the variables `X` and `R`. Again, it's unclear what it is you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with other solution,

```
final_func(C) :- (func1(X,m) -> other_func(m) ; other_func(n)).
```

My problem is solved, but this is not correct solution because it only works for  one case.